# jQuery Context Menu - Ignore Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am using this jQuery [Context Menu plugin](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) for one of my tools I am working on. My selector is set to trigger the menu any time some one right clicks on a table row:

```
selector: 'tbody tr',
```

While this is working perfectly, a user is not able to access the normal context menu if they were to right click on a link.

I would like to be able to prevent this context from working if right clicking on a link. To do this, I have tried altering my selector to be:

```
selector: 'tbody tr:not(a)',
```

This however is still not preventing the issue from occurring.

Is there another selector in jQuery that can be used to exclude links?

Comment: This is not quite the answer to your problem, but you could attach the menu to cells that do not containing links e.g. `tbody td:not(:has(a))`.

Comment: @Mikey - This seemed to work fine but on second look, the plugin no longer functions when trying to identify where the click came from. I will try and reach out to the plugins author to find a workaround